# Adding controls dynamically on a Windows Forms form

Tags: windows, winforms

I am trying to add a bunch of controls dynamically in rows and columns in a Windows Forms form. For example, if I have 20 controls and I need to create three columns and n rows. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a `TableLayoutPanel` to your form. At runtime, instantiate your controls using the `new` keyword. Add them to the `tableLayoutPanel.Controls` collection. You can either add them to specific rows and columns, or let panel have them flow into the next available cell.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Tim.

However, if you know that you are always going to be adding the controls in sets of three, I would recommend creating a user control to contain the three.